# 3D text effect using Three.js is not working in the browser

Tags: three.js

For learning purpose I tried to create a 3D text effect using Three.js I installed using npm. I ran browser using Live server extension in VScode but output is not loading, it is blank. What's wrong in my code? Why can't I generate a 3D text?

Package.json added "type": "Module"

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3D Text Effect</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/three/build/three.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Three.js code in script.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");


var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 5;


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
fontLoader.load('fonts/droid/droid_sans_bold.typeface.json', function(font) {


var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry("Hello Three.js", {
  font: new THREE.Font(font),
  size: 2,
  height: 0.5,
  curveSegments: 12,
  bevelEnabled: true,
  bevelThickness: 0.2,
  bevelSize: 0.1
});
  

var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });

var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);

scene.add(textMesh);
  
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();  
  
});
```

Comment: 2 problems I see. You are loading your script and trying to use three.js before loading three.js, switch your script tags around. Also, your loading `three.min.js`, you probably want to load `three.module.js`

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion, 

<script src="./node_modules/three/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js"></script>
 <script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>

now output showing as black color and showing error as "TextGeometry is not a constructor"

Comment: Because TextGeometry lives in the examples. add `<script src="./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js"></script>`. Also, you dont need both three.min.js and three.module.js

Comment: I could be wrong about how I think modules work directly in the browser, I always use a build tool like rollup or webpack.. Adding a build tool/step to combine all your code would probably get around these problems you seem to be having... maybe take a look at [this docs page](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation)